# jQuery show on hover, hide when mouse moves away

Tags: jquery, html, hover, hide, show

I have a div that I want to work similarly to a hamburger menu. When mouse hovers over *#Nnav*, *.dd* should appear and then disappear again when unhovering. I don't know what is missing, but the div is always visible (tried hiding it with CSS and then it always remained hidden). Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
 <img class="Nmenu" id="Nnav" src="images/nav.png">
  <div class="Nmenu" id="dd">
   <div class="Nmenu" id="dropdown"></div>
    <a class="Nmenu buttons" id="B1" href="#">Page 1</a>
    <a class="Nmenu buttons" id="B2" href="#">Page 2</a>
    <a class="Nmenu buttons" id="B3" href="#">Page 3</a>
 </div> </div>
```

CSS:

```
#dd {display: none;}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#Nnav").on({
mouseover: function() {
    $("#dd").stop().show();
},
mouseout: function() {
    $("#dd").stop().hide();
} })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#dd {
    display: none;
}
#Nnav:hover + #dd {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <img class="Nmenu" id="Nnav" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    
    <div class="Nmenu" id="dd">
        <div class="Nmenu" id="dropdown"></div>
        <a class="Nmenu buttons" id="B1" href="#">Page 1</a>
        <a class="Nmenu buttons" id="B2" href="#">Page 2</a>
        <a class="Nmenu buttons" id="B3" href="#">Page 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This isn't going to work as a menu toggler, though, since the menu disappears once you're off the image. You'd need the menu to be a child element:

```css
#dd {
    display: none;
}

#Nnav {
    display: inline-block;
}

#Nnav:hover #dd {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Nnav">
    <img class="Nmenu" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">

    <div class="Nmenu" id="dd">
        <div class="Nmenu" id="dropdown"></div>
        <a class="Nmenu buttons" id="B1" href="#">Page 1</a>
        <a class="Nmenu buttons" id="B2" href="#">Page 2</a>
        <a class="Nmenu buttons" id="B3" href="#">Page 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want to do it with jQuery you can just toggle the class on/off

```
$("#Nnav").on({
    mouseover: function() {
            $("#dd").toggleClass('dd');
    },
    mouseout: function() {
            $("#dd").toggleClass('dd');
    }
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9rq5e20/1/)

Comment: This achieves the OP's actual request, but it doesn't work very well as a menu, eh?

Comment: @isherwood i would do it with CSS if possible, you can get a long way with various combinations of pseudo selectors

Comment: Doesn't matter what tool you use. This UX is not viable.

Comment: @isherwood please explain

Comment: Did you try clicking the links in your demo? It explains itself.

Comment: You can easily attach a click event as it is done with the mouseover/mouseout events

Answer (score 0):

CSS selector is wrong. You need # when selecting element with id

```
#dd {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Looks like that was a typo on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the css. dd is not a class it is an id. It should be #dd {display: none;} not .dd {display: none;}

Comment: This answer was already provided, and it appears that it was a typo on the question anyway.